# Faster `elem` Using Binary Search In Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of `Text`s, and they are in sorted order. Seems to me that I can write a much faster version of `elem` by implementing it as a binary search instead of a linear search. Does such a version exist already?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskell's lists are implemented as linked lists, meaning that access to an arbitrary `i`-th element is in `O(i)`. In normal usages, binary search version of `elem` for lists would take more time than the standard version (see @DanielFischer's remark below).

You may wish to use a different container, such as [Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html) or[Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html), that are implemented as a balanced binary tree, which gives gives you `O(log n)` access time (where `n` is the number of elements in the map/set).

Comment: [`Data.Set`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.4.2.1/Data-Set.html) might be a more appropriate container to switch to.

Comment: @dave4420: Added, thanks. I completely forgot to mention it :)

Comment: [`Data.HashSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/latest/doc/html/Data-HashSet.html) might be a possibility too.

Comment: Just to be overly pedantic: A binary search on a linked list may be faster than a linear search if the comparison is very expensive. So if the `Text`s all had a 100M long common prefix, ...

Comment: If the list is not modified after creation, e.g. it was created by reading a list of words in alphabetical order from a file (e.g. a dictionary) and it is searched often then it is probably space and time efficient to create a vector or array and use binarySearch on that.

Answer (score 6):

Binary search requires random access. Since a haskell list does not provide random access (accessing an element in the middle takes linear time), binary search would not be helpful.

If your data was in an `Array`, which provides random access, binary search would be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a list of Texts, and they are in sorted order.

Change the data structure, and your algorithms will be obvious (to paraphrase Brooks).

This is particularly true of Haskell, where our data structures are typically not in terms of mutable arrays (meaning you don't get to fall back on pointer hacking).

If you use e.g. a heap or tree to store your text, you'll be able to implement *O(log(n))* elem trivially. You can take advantage of the fact they're sorted to provide faster insert.